# class not found exception in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop

When I tried the below query

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ hadoop jar /home/cloudera/workspace/para.jar word.Paras examples/wordcount examples/output3; 

15/11/05 10:13:04 INFO mapred.JobClient: map 0% reduce 0% 15/11/05 10:13:18 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201511050944_0005_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class word.Paras$Map not found.
```

Here word is package name Paras is class name I have checked the output file is created as logs.

How can I fix this issue.

Thanks,
Anbu k

Comment: Can you provide the implementation of `word.Paras` class.

Comment: I am not understanding your question. means you  are asking about the program

Comment: yes post your code....

Comment: Hi,
I tried with another class and its working fine now. thanks for your reply